# SQL Error 1452 : Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, debugging

I am trying to install Zabbix by following this [guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/monitoring/monitoring-servers-with-zabbix). I ran into the following problems when trying to run data.sql after running scheme.sql successfully

```
mysql -D zabbix -uzabbix -pPassword < /home/zabbix/zabbix-2.4.5/database/mysql/schema.sql

mysql -D zabbix -uzabbix -pPassword < /home/zabbix/zabbix-2.4.5/database/mysql/data.sql
```

> ERROR 1452 (23000) at line 2989: Cannot add or update a child row: a
>   foreign key constraint fails ('zabbix'.'sysmaps_elements', CONSTRAINT
>   'c_sysmaps_elements_2' FOREIGN KEY ('iconid_off') REFERENCES 'images'
>   ('imageid'))

I cannot figure out why I would not be able to add or update a child row , it looks perfectly fine to me.

The scripts can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/44ij0872pt0qpvs/AADUixuIDh5KXGkiCIn2NeMna?dl=0)

Comment: So `iconid_off` in all rows being inserted to `sysmaps_elements` already exists as a value for `imageid` in `images`? The script should be inserting in that order. What does line 2989 of the script contain?

Answer (score 0):

1. check the order of sql execution.
   schema.sql --> images.sql --> data.sql
2. Make sure the image data is actually entered.
   select * from images;

This is because images.sql is not executed because autocommit is not set in some DBs.
This is because there is no "commit;" in the last sentence of images.sql.
so add the statement "commit;" to images.sql.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your data.sql with a header and a footer like the following :

-- Add these lines as a header to your MYSQL data script

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

-- Add these lines as a footer  to your MYSQL data script

```
 UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;    
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
```

This will enable you to restore data without any foreign-cheking.

> updated :
> you can re-build you data.sql file by including the header and footer :

```
cat header.sql data.sql footer.sql > data_NEW.sql
```